# Tkinter Radiobutton "indicatoron" value doesn't effect anything

Tags: python, tkinter

Using Tkinter in Python 3.5, trying to create a series of radiobuttons without indicators (ie. regular push buttons). I set "indicatoron" to 0 but it still appears with indicators. I tried changing the value to 99999, 0.25, -1, and it always appears with indicators (except when I tried to set it to a string, then it told me it was expecting a boolean). What am I doing wrong?

Code snippet:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    term=tk.IntVar()
    b1=tk.Radiobutton(root, text="1", variable=term, value=1, indicatoron=0).pack()
    b2=tk.Radiobutton(root, text="2", variable=term, value=2, indicatoron=0).pack()
    b3=tk.Radiobutton(root, text="3", variable=term, value=3, indicatoron=0).pack()
    b4=tk.Radiobutton(root, text="4", variable=term, value=4, indicatoron=0).pack()
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? Your code works for me on OSX.

Comment: Windows here, works fine.

Comment: I'm also on OSX. The code works for me in that it doesn't crash, but it won't appear as push buttons. Could I be using a newer version of Tkinter?

Comment: You may want to increase the `borderwidth` value to make it easier to see the state of the control.

Comment: To clarify: when I use that code, the buttons appear like in the first picture. I want them to look like the buttons in the second picture, but still have a value attached to them. http://imgur.com/a/2fI02

Comment: Off-topic: The `.pack()` method returns `None`, so `b1`, `b2`, etc are all being set to that value.

Comment: I phrased that a bit wrong. I meant that the buttons still give a value to the variable "term" ie. not using the regular button() widget

Comment: Could be an issue with 3.5, I'm using 3.4 and it works fine.

Comment: If anyone actually has a working setup on Mac, could you describe your install? It seems to be linked to a limitation in Cocoa, so could it be worked around by installing a standalone Tcl if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to not work on OSX.  In essence this flag does not work for radiobuttons or checkbuttons, and has not for many years.

This is the reason given by the TK team ...

> it is mapped to a specific Cocoa button style (NSSwitchButton) that does not allow us to turn off the checkmark

The full [official response](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/3580159fffffffffffff) (back in 2012), in regards to the checkbutton is ...

wordtech added on 2012-11-07 22:02:38:
As discussed in the Tkinter mailing list:

"After looking at the code that implements the checkbutton, it appears that, internally, it is mapped to a specific Cocoa button style (NSSwitchButton) that does not allow us to turn off the checkmark. I suppose we'll have to add this to the list of Tk configuration flags that are ignored in certain contexts when Mac-native widgets are used (background, relief, etc.). " 
This is the less useful responce to the problem logged against the radiobutton ... [It works for me](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/2886983fffffffffffff)

It is unclear why some people on OSX seem to have this working.